# How to remove the "Example value" section for binary files in Swagger UI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

One of the API routes returns a file. Since it responds with no body, I wanted to remove the "Example Value" section in Swagger UI instead of leaving what it inserts as default `string`.

Is there a way to remove the "Example Value" entirely from the Swagger UI documentation in FastAPI?

Or is there a reason why it should be kept even though the response has no body, but a file?

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
from starlette.responses import FileResponse

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/",
            response_class=FileResponse,
            responses={
                200: {
                    "content": {"application/octet-stream": {}}
                }
            },
            )
async def get_file():
    ...
    return FileResponse(file_path, media_type='application/octet-stream', filename=filename)
```

Swagger UI with Example value = string:

[image]

#### What I've tried

Setting example to `None` gives the same result as when it is not explicitly declared.

Setting example as an empty string is the closest I've gotten to the expected result, but I would like for that section to be removed entirely instead of keeping it empty if there's no example model at all.

```py
responses={200: {
    "content": {"application/octet-stream": {
        "example": ""
    }}
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a Swagger UI issue/limitation, not FastAPI's. Here's the related enhancement request: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4791